# Constructing measure using a non-monotonic function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

It's well-known that we can construct a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ using a Stieltjes measure function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is a non-decreasing right continuous function (see for example Durret Theorem 1.1.4). The steps are as follows:

1. Consider the semi-algebra $\mathcal{S}=\{(a,b]\cap \mathbb{R}: -\infty\le a\le b \le \infty\}$ and define $\mu((a,b]\cap \mathbb{R}) = F(b)-F(a)$. By the telescoping series argument, it can be shown that $\mu$ is finitely additive on $\mathcal{S}$.
2. Using the right continuity of $F$ and Heine-Borel theorem, it can be sown that $\mu$ is countably sub-additive on $\mathcal{S}$.
3. Now extension theorems can be invoked in order to extend the measure $\mu$ to the algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{S})$ and then (the resulsting measure is $\sigma$-finite) to the sigma-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

I think the monotonicity of $F$ is only required for $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} F(x) = a \  \text{or} \pm\infty$ to be true. Is it possible to consider a non-monotonic function $F$ and only require the mentioned condition? I mean considering function $F$ such that $F$ is right continuous and $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} F(x) = a \  \text{or} \ \pm\infty.$$

Comment: Montonicity is tied to positiveness of the measure. You can construct signed measures  when $F$ is not monotonic. Ref Rudin's RCA

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks. So the positiveness of the measure implies monotonicity? And the same steps can be used to construct signed measures?

Comment: Yes. Note that $F(y)-F(x)=\mu ((x,y]) \ge 0$ for $x<y$ if $\mu$ is  a positive measure.  No such requirement for a  signed measure.

Comment: @geetha290krm Great! If you like you can add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is a real function of bounded variation which is right continuous then there is a unique real measure $\mu$ on The Borel $\sigma-$ algebra of $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu ((-\infty, x])=F(x)$ for all $x$. In fact, we can even take $F$ to be complex valued, in which case $\mu$ becomes a complex measure. Further, $F$ is monotonically increasing if and only if $\mu$ is a positive measure.

Comment: Just one last question. Do you know any textbook or any other source that applies the above steps for constructing a signed measure? By steps I mean $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{S}) \to \sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

Comment: Yes, it was there as a theorem in an earlier edition of Rudin's RCA. For some reason Rudin made it an exercise in the later editions.  @S.H.W

Comment: Thanks for the answer.